# Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, typescript, module

I want to import Pipe Module to my app,

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'values',  pure: false })
export class PipeModule implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {
    return Object.keys(value).map(key => value[key]);
  }

  static forRoot() {
      return {
          ngModule: PipeModule,
          providers: [],
      };
   }
}
```

this is my pipe module

at my
**app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
   ...,
    PipeModule.forRoot()
```

I import it like this and I get this error

```
Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'AppModule
```

Answer (score 19):

I got the same error (which is very generic), but for a totally different reason.

My solution won't solve the original question, but I write it here anyway in case someone has the same problem:

In my unit tests, I was accidentally declaring a `provider` object inside the `imports` array instead of the `providers` one. That was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `PipeModule` is not decorated with the `@NgModule` decorator - so it's not a module. Hence it can't be imported into your `AppModule` - only `@NgModules` are allowed to be imported.

Based on what you're doing, your first code example is just creating a standard Angular pipe so please change the name of that class to something like `ValuesPipe` so it's not misleading.

At that point, you have two options: you can declare your new `ValuesPipe` in `AppModule` or you can create a whole new `NgModule` to store your new `ValuesPipe` and then import that new `NgModule` into your `AppModule`.

Please note that in both options below, I've assumed that you've renamed the class in your first example to `ValuesPipe`.

**so, Option 1:**

in **app.module.ts**,

```
declarations: [
  .....,
  ValuesPipe,
]
```

Or **Option 2:**

create a new class **PipeModule** looking like:

```
@NgModule({
   imports: CommonModule,  (from @angular/core)
   declarations: ValuesPipe,
})
export class PipeModule { }
```

And then, in **app.module.ts**,

```
imports: [
  ......,
  PipeModule
]
```

Comment: thank you for the clear answer! I went with the declarations part which I found it easier to implement